# How to get and pass object(JSON API) in React/Redux?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

i have a problem with getting and passing JSON object (info) from Store in React "Container" to his child component (InfoPage) via props.. 
Also i had Action's and Reducer's methods, all of there works without mistakes. 
Could somebody help me with this. 
This is my code from "Container".
thanks.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.auth.user,
    info: state.info,
    ui: state.ui
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, uiActions,
    authActions, infoActions), dispatch);
}

class Info extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
    ui: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
    info: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
    switchProfileMenu: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    logOut: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClickOption = this.handleClickOption.bind(this);
  }

  handleClickOption() {
    return this.props;
  }
  
  render() {
    const { user, logOut, info, ui: { showProfileMenu },
      switchProfileMenu } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={b()}>
        <Header
          user={user}
          logOut={logOut}
          switchMenu={switchProfileMenu}
          showMenu={showProfileMenu}
        />
        <div className="container">
          <div className="content">
            <div>
              <InfoPage data={info} />
              sadasd
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey man! Is that all your code? Is your component connected to the store using `connect` high order component? I don't see it here!

Comment: It's almost half of file without imports and yes there is connect in the conteiner's bottom.   (export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Info);)

Comment: Dude, I don't see anything wrong in the code here! If your reducer creates a new object and the JSON object you get (info) has some changes, everything should be fine! How you dispatch the action to fetch/update the info JSON object?

Comment: @Ematipico I'm dispatch the action like that:https://jsfiddle.net/vnam92/nvhf7e5d/1/  Could you help with realization of this.. Where and how i need to invoke this method to upload json object into container`s child, by props.

Comment: @Ematipico also webpack informs, component's input object is undefined... im stocked...

Comment: Ok, you have to manage to call the function getInfo(). How your application calls that function? I will try to write a response but I also need to see how you create your store and `Provider`

Comment: @Ematipico Exactly, I can not understand how to write this method or methods so that they change the Store.. Please help me) I updated jsfiddle. There are CreateStore file and Provider of my project..

Answer (score 0):

I gave a look to your code and there are some missing parts.

First, the function `getInfo` looks to be a thunk (`redux-thunk`, which allows you to execute asynchronous operations). You have to import it inside your index and initialize it is, not an array

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
// ...
createStore(rooReducer, applyMiddlewares(thunk))
```

You can define you `mapDispatchToProps` in a simple way, for now:

```
import getInfo from './actions'
//  ....
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatchGetInfo(id) {
      dispatch(getInfo(id))
    }
  }
}
```

Inside your component Info, implement like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
  const { dispatchGetInfo, params: { id } } = this.props
  // I PRESUME your `id` is inside the params of react router, feel free to change if not
  dispatchGetInfo(id) // => this should call your thunk which will call your consecutive dispatcher
}
```

EDIT

Your index file should contain this modified line

```
<Route name="app:info" path="information/:id" component={Info} />
```

Comment: It's been a while that I don't use `redux-thunk`. I usually go for `redux-saga`. To me it looks  more neat and simple

Comment: It depends on how the rest of your code is done. I just gave you an example of how you should return the actions! In the end, what you really have to do, **is to call the function that calls the action `getInfo`**. Please check my edited response

Comment: Yes I guess you can :)